# PostgreSQL And Swagger data type incompatibility

Tags: node.js, reactjs, swagger

but I'm getting an error about data types. I have a total of 4 data types
postgresql
1- id                  bigint
2- name             character varying
3- location         character varying
4- price_range       integer

Swagger does not accept these data types. What can I use in swagger instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only accepted swagger data types are:

```
string (this includes dates and files)
number
integer
boolean
array
object
```

from https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

Comment: thank you for your answer, there is no direct string in postgresql, there is cstring. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: you can use varchar to store strings in postgres. I want you to notice though, that postgres and swagger are two fundamentally different technologies. There doesn't necessarily need to be an exact match between the types because one concerns with exposing an interface to a rest api and the other to store data in a database. Feel free to mark the answer as solved if it helped you.